# Eclipse Editor highlight syntax errors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

just implemented a custom editor with syntax checker etc.
The creation of markers working well on saving editor and are displayed in the problem view.
But how to underline the error in the editor. What I missed?

Now:
[image: currentstatus]

Should be:
[image: shouldbestatus]

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
         <specification
            icon = "icons/fail.gif"
            annotationType="com.customeditor"
            verticalRulerPreferenceKey="highlight.rulers.vertical"
            textPreferenceKey="highlight.text"
            colorPreferenceKey="highlight.color"
            highlightPreferenceKey="highlight.background"
            textPreferenceValue="true"
            textStylePreferenceValue="PROBLEM_UNDERLINE"
            overviewRulerPreferenceKey="highlight.rulers.overview"
            presentationLayer="4"
            highlightPreferenceValue="true"
            label="DiffSiteB"
            symbolicIcon="error"
            colorPreferenceValue="255,0,0"
            verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"
            overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
            textStylePreferenceKey="highlight.text.style" >
        </specification >
    </extension>
```

```java
public IMarker createMarker(IResource res, String location, String message, int start, int end) throws CoreException {
  IMarker marker = null;

  if (res != null) {
     marker = res.createMarker("com.customedtior");
     marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
     marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, start);
     marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, end);
     marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, location);
     marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, message);
         
     SimpleMarkerAnnotation ann = new SimpleMarkerAnnotation(marker);
     ann.setType(JavaMarkerAnnotation.ERROR_ANNOTATION_TYPE);
     getVerticalRuler().getModel().addAnnotation(ann, new Position(start, end));
     getVerticalRuler().update();
  }
  return marker;
}
```

Comment: An editor based on what? Have you set up an annotation model in the source viewer? Read the "Source viewers and annotations" section in Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Editors in the Eclipse help.

Comment: Still not get the error underlined. My custom editor extends `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`. But is it maybe the wrong configuration of the extension point?

Comment: You have to do a lot more work to get the editor to show the markers, this is described in the help. Have you set up an annotation model for marker annotations?

Comment: I added 
`<extension
 point="org.eclipse.core.filebuffers.annotationModelCreation">
 <factory
  extensions="*"
  class="org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ResourceMarkerAnnotationModelFactory">
 </factory>
</extension>`

and the rest is the implemenation of `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`. As I see it is mostly the same as in the help.

Comment: Maybe anything missing here?
 `protected void configureSourceViewerDecorationSupport(SourceViewerDecorationSupport support) {

  Iterator<AnnotationPreference> e= fAnnotationPreferences.getAnnotationPreferences().iterator();
  while (e.hasNext())
   support.setAnnotationPreference(e.next());

  support.setCursorLinePainterPreferenceKeys(CURRENT_LINE, CURRENT_LINE_COLOR);
  support.setMarginPainterPreferenceKeys(PRINT_MARGIN, PRINT_MARGIN_COLOR, PRINT_MARGIN_COLUMN);
 }`

Comment: This looks the same as the code in `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`. Did you try calling `super.configureSourceViewerDecorationSupport(support);` instead or not overriding this at all?

Comment: yes I copied just the same, not override it

Comment: Can I download any sample which has such like a support?

Comment: Just figered out the problem
by commenting this out
`setPreferenceStore(MyPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore( ));`
The preference store settings in my editor were preventing the
red squiggles from rendering.